# How to put together data from different tables without duplicating

Tags: sql, select, join

Im feeling a bit stupid now but I cant seem to make it happen. I have som tables with data and the problem I have with one SELECT is that the data is sometimes duplicated. (Sorry, English is not my first language, ask if unclear.

```
SELECT (IM_FAKTUROR.FAKT_NUMMER || ' ' || IM_FAKTURA_GRUPPER.FAKT_TYP) AS 'ProjektNrNamn',
```

But sometimes those two tables/columns have exactly the same data and in those cases I only want the data from one of them, not both. **How to?**

If there is different data in the two I want all info.

Comment: Have you tried UNION?

Comment: Use a `case` expression in the select list. (But it seems a bit odd to mix up those different values. In invoice id is not the same as an invoice type.)

Comment: I know It sounds a bit odd but im trying to handle some old data where there wasnt very good control over where people added what kind of data. =) So I want to make a presentation where the data is combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `case` expression. If the two columns have the same value, just return one of them. Else return both of them:

```
SELECT case when IM_FAKTUROR.FAKT_NUMMER = IM_FAKTURA_GRUPPER.FAKT_TYP
            then IM_FAKTUROR.FAKT_NUMMER
       else (IM_FAKTUROR.FAKT_NUMMER || ' ' || IM_FAKTURA_GRUPPER.FAKT_TYP)
       end AS 'ProjektNrNamn',
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProjektNrNamn FROM
(
SELECT (IM_FAKTUROR.FAKT_NUMMER || ' ' || IM_FAKTURA_GRUPPER.FAKT_TYP) AS 'ProjektNrNamn'
) as t
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    IM_FAKTUROR.FAKT_NUMMER || ' ' || IM_FAKTURA_GRUPPER.FAKT_TYP AS 'ProjektNrNamn'
FROM ...
```

But this answer assumes that the project name is the only thing in your select list.  If you have other columns, it gets more complicated.